# How do you type an immutablejs Map keys?

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

How do you type an immutablejs Map keys, in my case to force an a key of  'id' and value of number?

so I tried different variation, such as:

```
let campaignSelected: Map<{id: string},number>;
```

but no love.

```
Error:(12, 13) TS2322:Type 'Map<string, number>' is not assignable to type 'Map<{ id: string; }, number>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
```

also tried with no luck:

```
type myIdType = {id: number}

export interface IMsDatabase {
    uiState: {
        campaign: {
            timelineSelected: Map<myIdType,number>;
         }
    }
}
```

thanks for reading,

Sean

Comment: Add the code which instantiates the map

Comment: looks like a fix is coming: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/683#event-990857809

Answer (score 0):

To map through an immutable object you would set a your state to be something like this:

```
campaign: {timelineSelected: myIdType.map(item=>{item.number})
```

This might be unrelated but if you wanted just the specific value without having to map through the immutable object you would call `myIdType.get('id')`